# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'flip'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[image]

Error message: 
    AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'flip'

I can't understand why it's giving me this error, I've googled and made sure I'm up to the latest version of numpy. I definitely don't have another file called numpy in my working directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) Quote: **New in version 1.12.0.** Your version: 1.11.3 - and please post code and error messages as text, not as images.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`np.flip` has been introduced for versions v.1.12.0 and beyond. For older versions, you can consider using [`np.fliplr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr) and [`np.flipud`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html#numpy-flipud).

Alternatively, upgrade your numpy version using `pip install --user --upgrade numpy`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes,`flip` is new, but there isn't anything magical about it.  Here's the code:

```
def flip(m, axis):
    if not hasattr(m, 'ndim'):
        m = asarray(m)
    indexer = [slice(None)] * m.ndim
    try:
        indexer[axis] = slice(None, None, -1)
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError("axis=%i is invalid for the %i-dimensional input array"
                         % (axis, m.ndim))
    return m[tuple(indexer)]
```

The essence of the action is that it indexes your array with one or more instances of `::-1` (the `slice(None,None,-1)`).  `flipud/lr` do the same thing.

With this `x`, `flip` does:

```
In [826]: np.array([1,2,3])[::-1]
Out[826]: array([3, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

One can reshape 1-D array apply `fliplr` and then get 1-D array back. That is possible to go from 1-D `x` to 2-D by using, e.g. `x.reshape(1,x.size)` or `[x]`.

```
x = np.arange(5)
print(x)
x = np.fliplr([x])[0];  # fliplr works with at least 2-D arrays
print(x)
```

> [0 1 2 3 4]
>   [4 3 2 1 0]

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation about what the problem is and how this code helps.