# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'flip', python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a code that might have been developed for Python 3, but my Centos is running Python 2.7:

```
def generateWeights(self, name_list):
    n = len(name_list)
    weights = np.flip(np.arange(1, n), axis=0)
    return weights / np.sum(weights)
```

I get for this part of the code:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'flip'

Is there anything I should install/update, or an alternative code that will work?

**Import part:**

```
import requests
import urllib
import logging
import argparse
from lxml import objectify
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
```

Comment: install python 3. ```sudo yum install python34u python34u-wheel```

Comment: I can't. My webhost told me "Panel currently, does not support python3"

Comment: can you please give your full file code or at least **import** part.

Comment: or find some **python 2.7** compatible version of numpy.

Comment: @UmarAsghar updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'flip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706896/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-flip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html

> New in version 1.12.0.

Can you check your numpy version? Just run

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.version.version
```

from the interactive shell.

See [numpy reverse multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416170/numpy-reverse-multidimensional-array) for an alternative method to flipping an array.

Comment: `pip show numpy` returns Version: 1.7.1

I don't really know python, I just need to get this script to work, so I can't provide diff. method.

Comment: Start Python by running `python` from the terminal. Then enter the commands to check the version of numpy that is actually being used.

Comment: ok, still `1.7.1`. so should I ask my webhost to try upgrade for 1.12.0? or any easy command to this myself?

Comment: Yeah, so your Numpy is too old. It's just `pip install numpy --upgrade`, but maybe it's better to ask for support.